# Trying to make container div change height on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I am trying to make a container div change set height on click, but am having trouble getting it to work. I am not sure where I messed up and would love input as I am pretty new to Javascript.

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu').click(function() {

        $(".outer").css('height','600px ');
 });
 });
```

Here is a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r92cc51d/2/

Comment: Sorry, thank you for catching those mistakes, however it still does not work.

Comment: In your environment, or in JSFiddle? Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery attached to it, so regardless of syntax, it won't work. If you'd like your fiddle to work, click JAVASCRIPT > Frameworks & Libraries > jQuery 3.1.1.  [**Here is a fixed JSfiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/r92cc51d/10/)

Comment: in JSFiddle you need to specify the jquery framework.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're missing closing parenthesis for your click function:

```js
$('#menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.outer').css('height', '400px');
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

#menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div id="menu">
  
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to increase the height on click then you don't need to do it in JS. You can do it in html also.

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="menu" onClick = "document.getElementById('outer').style.height = '600px';">
  
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('outer').style.height = '600px';` *is* JavaScript.

Comment: ya I know but what I'm saying is " no need to do it in external js file"